# Autocomplete signatures from new C Headers

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, irony-mode

I use Emacs(work environment is Linux. and at home i use Windows 7) for most of my Python coding and documentation. I'm mostly working for visual effects pipeline products. Off late I'm learning bits of OpenGL and using C++ for that. I'm using the minimalist Gnu (C:/MinGW/)(`g++`) for compiling and I have been successfully compiling code.

I used `Visual Studio` once for the same purpose and I found out that once I have added the libraries to the project's auto-complete or intellisence(whatever vs uses) adapted to the new libraries. for example in SFML vs2017 was predicting all `sf::` namespace elements. I've Auto-complete for general C++ mode in Emacs how do i make it read from GLFW or SFML or GLEW or ncurses libraries.

(I saw a lot on discussions about `company-mode` and `clang` and `irony` and `sarcasm` but makes it no sense as `g++` compiler is not mentioned anywhere.)

Comment: Is using cedet the way??

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls and https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode ? It works great for C and C++. You just need to generate a `compile_commands.json` for your project. Instructions for generating it are given at https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls/wiki/Project-Setup .